# Get multiple Graph Subscription event

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I am setting up graph api subscriptions (with changeType: created,updated) to listen to my calendar events. It works perfectly, when I create an event I received a notification. The problem is that I receive two notifications:

- For my changeType:created
- For my changeType:updated

Each time I receive a created notification, I store that event in an external database and if I change the date event in my outlook, I want to update that data event in my external database.

But I wondering if we could only send on changeType:created subscription with no changeType:updated ?Or is it impossible and I will always receive two notifications ?

If I have to keep the two subscriptions approach, how can I know that two subscriptions related to this specific event ?

I just want to find the best approach.

I tried to create an event without title to see if I received two notifications but I always receive two notifications.